# Grails 1.3.7 spring security - No thread-bound request found at start

Tags: grails, spring-security

Suffering badly from the bug below.

See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-98

Works fine in my mac os x environment but fails badly on my collegues ubuntu.

/S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the resources plugin seems to fix it for us.